# How to kill a process in Windows by batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have no previous batch scripting knowledge. So the question could sound a bit silly. My target is to kill a process listening on a specific port.

I will pass the port number in the batch script argument.

```
@echo off
netstat -ano | findstr %1
```

This returns as follow:-

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       23708
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       23708
```

So if do it in the same script as :

```
taskkill /pid 23708 /F
```

It should kill the process. I don't know how to get the pid list in an array. How do I do it?

Comment: You should `...|find ":%1 "` instead of `...|findstr %1` to avoid false positives.

Comment: Just do this in your script:  `FOR /F "Tokens=5" %%A IN ('netstat -ano ^| findstr /I "0\.0\.0\.0:%1 " "\[::\]:%1 "') DO ( Taskkill /pid %%A /F)`  That will do the needful.

Comment: Or since you probably don;t want to only look for listening ports, and you probably do want to limit yourself to TCP you could use this:  `FOR /F "Tokens=5" %%A IN ('netstat -ano -p TCP ^| findstr /I ":%1 "') DO ( Taskkill /pid %%A /F)`